# Dynamic URL and Jinja templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, pymongo

I've been trying to create user interface to filter out results from my database. Important thing is that I want the filters to be 'additive'. So if user selects one filter, page redirects and displays results. After that, user can select another filter and the results are narrowed down to **both** filters. This should continue for any number of filters.

This is how it looks now

```py
@app.route('/')
def home():

    kind = request.args.get('kind')
    price = request.args.get('price')
    category = request.args.get('category')

    filters = {}
    if price is not None: filters['params.price'] = {'$lt' : int(price) }
    if kind is not None: filters['kind'] = kind
    if category is not None: filters['category'] = category

    posts = db.collection.find(filters)

    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
```

and links for my hrefs using jinja2 templates look like

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for ('home', kind='m') }}">Label</a></<li>
<li><a href="{{ url_for ('home', price=50000)}}">Label</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url_for ('home', category='p') }}">Label</a></li>
... many more similar links
```

Currently this works as override for the URL. If I click any of those links it just replaces the whole URL and uses the variable from the link.

```
first link: http://127.0.0.1/?kind=m
second link: http://127.0.0.1/?price=5000
third link: http://127.0.0.1/?category=p
```

What I'd like it to do is to append the query - If i click any of the links it remembers previous selected filters and 'adds' last clicked link. Below I show how I expect for it to work.

```
first link: http://127.0.0.1/?kind=m
second link: http://127.0.0.1/?kind=m?price=50000
second link: http://127.0.0.1/?kind=m?price=50000?category=p
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass all filter values (`None` initially) to the view, and add them as arguments to the `url_for` calls. Filters which are `None` will not be included in the links.

Comment: I did something like this:

`def home(price=None, kind=None, category=None):`

and for the links:
`<a href="{{ url_for ('home', category='p', price=price, kind=kind) }}">`

but this ends up in browser as empty varbiales in URL bar:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/?price=50000&category=&kind=`

//sorry about the formating

Comment: Ok, so what I was missing was actually passing the variables in render template. It works! Thank you